# How to make openssl show all the functions its calling during a handshake?

Tags: tls, openssl

I have the following code in my program and it calls many functions from the openssl library, e.g. `do_hadshake(*ssl)`, to connect to a server.

```
 if (SSL_connect(ssl) <= 0) { ... }
```

What I'm looking for is how to get output on terminal, showing all the operation it is running, e.g. performing public key encryption, private key encryption, etc.  What code should I write that will give me such output in a terminal?

I am doing this on Linux Mint.

Comment: Actually, I want to output all the steps in Handhake process , like those hello messages,finish messages, etc..

Comment: OpenSSL has no such functionality built in but you can use a debugger to get what you want.  How to do this is off-topic here but you can see [Tool to trace local function calls in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311840/tool-to-trace-local-function-calls-in-linux#311912) for more details.

Comment: If you want to see the messages that are being exchanged by your application rather than the function calls, you can attach a packet capture tool like Wireshark, you'll be able to see the handshake. If you also need to dissect the encrypted part, you'll need to tell Wireshark the private key or capture the session key so Wireshark can decrypt the communication (https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL).

Comment: Is any verbose logging feature is present in openssl